# assemblies for NETFramework,Version=v4.5 were not found

Tags: asp.net

I am migrating a VS2010 web app to VS2022, I am targeting 4.8.
When trying to publish I get the err
"reference assemblies for NETFramework,Version=v4.5 were not found"
Question: Which developer pack should I install 4.5 or 4.8?
When I went to the MS download page the 4.5 developer pack was marked as not supported or downloadable.
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks
As the app starts up it give we a choice of targeting 4.8 or 4.5 when I choose 4.5 it tells me to download the 4.5 developer pack
Thank you in advance

Comment: It might be easier to go in stages, perhaps VS2017 would be a good intermediary between VS2010 and VS2022.

Comment: Andrew Morton, I had the same idea and tried VS2017 first. It didn't convert and open. It converted and opened in VS2022. The App runs on my PC, but I get the error when I select Publish Web Site.

Comment: Thank you Andrew Morton.  I went back to try VS2017 , just to view the error paragraphs it had shown  me several times before,  and wala it just opened up my app and all the web pages worked with out a single fix on my part.